# Highcharts: why 2D Pie displayed instead of 3D Pie?

Tags: asp.net-core, highcharts, blazor

I use Highcharts in my ASP.NET Core Blazor app.
Now I am testing how I can display 3D Pie. There is my json which I pass to the component

```
  string chartjson = @"{
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Contents of Highsoft\'s weekly fruit delivery'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: 100,
            depth: 45
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Delivered amount',
        data: [
            ['Bananas', 8],
            ['Kiwi', 3],
            ['Mixed nuts', 1],
            ['Oranges', 6],
            ['Apples', 8],
            ['Pears', 4],
            ['Clementines', 4],
            ['Reddish (bag)', 1],
            ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
        ]
    }]
}";

@inject Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime jsruntime;
    <link href="css/3DStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div id="@id.ToString()"></div>

    @code
{ [Parameter] public string Json { get; set; }
        private string id { get; set; } = "Highchart" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            StateHasChanged();
            base.OnParametersSet();
        }
        protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Json))
            {
                await jsruntime.InvokeAsync<string>("loadHighchart", new object[] { id, Json });
            }

            await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        } }
```

It works, I see the pie but it is 2D but not 3D as I need.
Also, if I remove this part from the json string it works as before.

```
 chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15
            }
        },
```

What is wrong?  How to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that is not a 3d pie with a "vertical" view? Try to put 45 on alpha instead of 15 to check it (if I put your pie code in https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-pie it's works fine)

Comment: Hi @ZedZip, Did you add the `highcharts-3d` module?

Comment: @Johna, yes, it works in jsfiddle but it is 2D in my Blazor app. Finally, I have decided do not use highcharts because it is not free. I get Plotly